# Scala asynchronous calculation using akka

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka, typesafe

im trying to design a program that will get a set of inputs (lets say some numbers)

it would do some calculation on each of the input and gather the result

I need this to be asynchronous calculation.

Looked into scala and akka and it looks perfect but i cant seem to understand the design of my actors and who will do that ?

for example : create 1 actor for each calc ? and 1 actor to collect all the results ?

any idea or documentations for designs using akka ?

Thanks!

Comment: You need all inputs to start the calculation? or there is one calculation per input?  What do you do with the result(s)?

Comment: for now i get a set of inputs and i need to make some calculations depending on the input type, after all calculations are finished i need to get the result set and me some more calculations on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this sample project

this is a example for a akka actor system that has 1 actor that gets a input set

for each input is will create a child actor that will calculate this and in the end will show the results from all the child actors

readme :
https://github.com/Nimrod007/Akka-Compute

code :
https://github.com/Nimrod007/Akka-Compute/blob/master/akkaComputeExample/src/main/scala/AkkaComputeApp.scala

Comment: just go to the root folder of the project

Answer (score 1):

I'm not answering your question directly since Nimrod007 already did it.  I'm not sure what your actual application is, but I just wanted to show you that using straight Futures might be a lot simpler.

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Example extends App {
  val futures = Range(1, 5).map(i => Future { i + 10 })
  val result = Future.fold(futures)(List.empty[Int])((answers, value) => value :: answers)
  result.onComplete(answersTry => answersTry.foreach(println))
  Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```

It does the same as Nimrod007's code, but is an awful lot shorter.

I don't mean that you should not use Akka.  But you should consider what is the most appropriate for your application.

Comment: this is short and clean but i need example using akka (the system will do more things later on and might be distributed later on)

Comment: another point to take in consideration is that in akka i can handle failures much easier